# gorm v2: what to do with what in v1 was gorm.Scope?

Tags: go-gorm

I'm migrating GORM to v2. **gorm.Scope** was removed in this version of GORM. I need TableName(), FieldByName() etc. Is there some replacement with the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was answered by [jinzhu](https://github.com/jinzhu):

https://gorm.io/docs/write_plugins.html

```
db.Statement.Schema.LookUpField("Name")
db.Statement.Table
```